# DevCenter reports syntax error but same CQL runs on cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I was trying to create a User Defined Function using Devcenter.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html

The following example was taken from the above link.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fLog (input double) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 'return Double.valueOf(Math.log(input.doubleValue()));';
```

It works in `cqlsh` but fails in DevCenter with the following error. Based on how fast I get the response, I think DevCenter does a local syntax check and aborts execution as it thinks the query is wrong.

I am using Cassandra 2.2.3 and DevCenter 1.4.1

[image]

Comment: DevCenter's query window is not a replica of CQLSH - not all commands that works on CQLSH will work in DevCenter. (`COPY` is another command that won't work)

Comment: COPY is kind of understandable as it might have to work with local file system but UDF creation would be considered DML and DML is allowed in DevCenter, so I'm inclined to think it is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

DevCenter does perform it's own grammar syntax checking as well as semantic validation.

This is a DevCenter bug - the column name "input" is not being allowed by the grammar in this context because it's also a CQL keyword that's incorrectly not being allowed here.

A suggested workaround until a fix is available is to change the name of the column, e.g. "inputvalue".

Answer (score 1):

As it says "No viable alternative at input '**input**'"

It seems like 'input' is a reserved keyword in Devcenter and not in the CQLSH.
Try using another name for the variable.